# Работа с буфером обмена системы в Vim

Tags: vim

Не получается вставить из буфера обмена системы текст в Vim.
Пытаюсь вставить с помощью регистров `"*` и `"+` , но они почему-то никак не взаимодействуют с буфером обмена системы.
В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

Пользуюсь Vim 8.1 из подсистемы Linux для Windows (Ubuntu 20.04.2)

Comment: насколько мне известно, wsl - это отдельная подсистема, и буфер обмена у нее свой. И соответственно если и заработает, то через ctrl+insert / shitf+insert

Comment: В другом терминале у меня это работало, в текущем почему-то не хочет :( А можно поподробнее про shift+insert? Я так понимаю имеется ввиду режим :set paste, но в этом режиме у меня почему-то при попытке нажать Shift+insert вместо текста из буфера вставляется <S-Insert>

Comment: shift-insert - это старый способ сделать вставку, работает в большинстве случаев и сейчас. в виме часто просто работает в режиме редактирования. Но что за другой "терминал"?

Comment: У меня не работает ни в режиме вставки, ни в режиме редактирования :( Под другим терминалом имею ввиду другой терминал/оболочку/версию linux из магазина приложений windows. Там внешние регистры нормально обрабатывались, но были другие более критичные для меня проблемы. В любом случае спасибо за ответы :)

Comment: терминал/оболочку/версию линукса - Вы понимаете, что это совершенно три разные вещи? лучше поставьте нормальный линукс (хоть в виртуалке) и будет больше толку и результата

Comment: Да, похоже придется :( Еще раз спасибо